# Why am I unable to inject angular-cookies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-cookies

I have

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-cookies.min.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

Everything loads correctly.

Then in my javascript I attempt to inject ngCookies:

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngCookies"]).
    config(function($cookies) {
         console.log($cookies.myCookie);
    });
```

But it does not seem to find $cookies:

```
 Unknown provider: $cookies from myApp
```

Comment: As stated on Angular documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) - Module Loading & Dependencies - *Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks*. That's why you are getting error `Unknown provider: $cookies from myApp` as `$cookies` is a service and therefore not available in `config` block.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm not sure what is your functional use-case but you can't inject services (`$cookies` is a service) inside config blocks. Only constants and providers can be injected inside config blocks.

You can inject services into run blocks but I don't know if this helps you since I'm not sure what are your trying to do with those cookies.

BTW: you seems to be mixing versions of the main angular file and the `ngCookies` module. This is not directly linked to your problem but this is rather odd.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "mixing versions"? Do I not need angular-cookies for the ngCookies module?

Comment: @JeffWong by mixing versions I mean that you've included the main angular module in version 1.0.3 while ngCookies in version 1.0.1. Normally both versions should be the same.

Comment: run blocks were the right answer. btw what are "constants" in this context?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) has that exact example from OP, can you elaborate on the last part of your answer?

Answer (score 11):

You can inject it manually:

```
myApp.config(function() {
  var $cookies;
  angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
    $cookies = _$cookies_;
  }]);

  // here you can use $cookies as usual
});
```

You might wonder  why do we have to specify `ngCookies` to the `injector()` call as WELL as to the `.invoke()` call?

`ngCookies` is name of the module (you'll need to have [angular-cookies.js](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies) in your project to be able to use this module). When you create injector by calling `injector()` you specify which modules should be used so that services from those modules can be used.

`invoke()` calls a function but let's you specify which services (provided by various modules) should be passed into the function (in our case service provided by `ngCookies` module is named `$cookies`)

This solution is a bit of a hack because you are manually creating new injector separate from the one that your angular app auto-creates and uses, but it should be safe because `ngCookie` seems to be only using functionalities of angular that don't keep their own state and are just thin wrappers of browser functionality.

Comment: I've been doing this and it works great, until minification, at which point it breaks horribly. I noticed that _ $cookies _, if changed, breaks, despite the injector annotation that *should* be minification-safe. _$cookies_ is not available in the ngCookies source, meaning that _$cookies_ is likely part of angular's magic. Need to investigate (unless you've found a way to minify with this already....)

Comment: FOr the record SO won't let me put underscores. Sorry for the confusion. I tried.

Comment: @dudewad I improved my answer to work with non-angular-aware minification.

Comment: Omg thank you. This is a perfect example of where the "angular way" is *absolutely* messed up. WHY are there so many ways to do this, and only one of them works for minification? E.g., why do we have to specify ngCookies to the injector() call as WELL as to the .invoke call? And why doesn't annotation, done exactly per the "minification-safe" specification on the angular site, work even when not minified in this context? Can you shed some light on that for me, because I'm totally missing it (see here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#annotate)

Comment: ...because exactly zero of the "annotation" methods they show there (which are confusing as it is since they never show you which of the methods one can use to get an instance of the injector is used) work, either when minified or not minified (at least, not in module.config). I get that this is a bit of a hack but you'd think that using cookies in a module config isn't terribly out of this world, and that they'd provide some way to make it happen. Ugh.

Comment: @dudewad Minification messes up variable and function names. Any scheme reliant on names will blow up. You need to pass service names as strings using second or third way listed at the url you gave to be out of reach of minification. Please keep in mind that no part of angular has any opportunity to run before minification. So it has to do what it can with result of minification where the parameter names are already lost.

Comment: @dudewad You could use https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ngmin or similar instead of generic minification that you are using so that angular files are minified carefully to preserve information that parameter names give to angular before minification.

Comment: @dudewad I'm in no way angular apologist. I think you are right that there should be obvious way to inject services into config, or at least cookies functionality. Possibly you could inject $cookiesProvider directly to config and use it to get instance of $cookie service to use it. I haven't tried that because I was able to get away with the solution I gave in this answer. Also it could be hard because applicaiton $injector is I think not fully initialized yet, at the time .config() runs.

Comment: yeah I agree, but I know how minification works and the way I was approaching it (which was any multitude of versions from their example pages character for character, or any multitude of combinations of other ideas) should have worked. For example when minifying a function that recieves an arg, the name of that argument should not affect whether or not minification breaks it since it's local to that function. So when changing it breaks it, it's exceptionally confusing if that's the only change. Or am I confused here? (I'm referring to the lamba function in the invoke() call)

Comment: @dudewad Inferring which service to inject into a function from parameter names is the most magic thing in angular. Other stuff is just complex and convoluted but this is magic hack that during run-time reads source code of your function (js gives you that when you cast function to string) and pareses parameter names from it. Lack of resilience against processing steps that mess up the source code is pretty easy to guess. It's a bit insane feature but I though it was well advertised.

Comment: To be honest, if I had read enough documentation to understand that angular reads your source like that, I would have heavily considered using another framework entirely. This feels like forcing other software patterns on something that JS isn't. I'll shut up now, that's a topic for a blog post!

Comment: Holy crap, it's threads like this that makes me think angular is doomed. What a cluster$!*#@

Comment: @user1391445 Think or hope? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue.
the angular version and the angular cookies version didn't match.
what i did to fix it is update bower.json to a working versions of both.

```
"angular": ">=1.2.*",
"angular-cookies": ">=1.2.*"
```

Then i ran:

```
bower install
```

i got this question:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
1) angular#1.3.13 which resolved to 1.3.13 and is required by angular-cookies#1.3.13 
2) angular#>=1.2.x <=1.4.x which resolved to 1.3.16 and is required by oclazyload#1.0.1 
3) angular#1.4.0 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-cookies#1.4.0 
4) angular#>=1.2.* which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by hashve 
5) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.11.2 
6) angular#>=1.2.26 <=1.5 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-translate#2.7.2 
7) angular#~1.x which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by restangular#1.5.1 
8) angular#^1.2.6 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-socket-io#0.6.1 
9) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.15 
10) angular#>=1.2.0 <1.5.0 which resolved to 1.4.0 and is required by angular-moment#0.10.1Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

Then I chose 3.

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/18971123/132374, it looks like you need to delare 'ngCookies' in your service module if you haven't already:

```
var serviceModule = angular.app('App.services', ['ngCookies']);
```

That worked for me.  Keep in mind that `$cookies` only works where Angular allows you to inject services (see the accepted answer for details).

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else stated, you cannot use the angular cookie service. However, there is no law known to man that says you cannot simply use document.cookie to access it and parse it yourself. Alternatively, you can create your own provider that gives you access to the cookies and you can inject that. Please remember that angular is simply a framework and when the framework has limitations you have to remember to use something called javascript.

Answer (score -11):

You should inject with name `$cookieProvider` instead `$cookies`:

```
angular.module("MyApp", ["ngCookies","ngRoute"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider","$cookiesProvider",
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $cookies) {

        }
    ]);
```

Comment: How do I use $cookiesProvider to get the cookie value?

Comment: This is a wrong answer in case anyone else is curious. There is no such thing as a $cookiesProvider service inside ngCookies. Not only that, but the factories inside of ngCookies don't get loaded until AFTER the config function runs.