# how to use cookiesProvider in angular config

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I want get cookie value and set to a provider. This post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20415679/772481 mentioned $cookiesProvider. But how do I use it?

```
mod.config(["someProvider", "$cookiesProvider", function(someProvider, $cookiesProvider) {
    someProvider.set('configs', {'token': $cookiesProvider["XSRF-TOKEN"]})
  }]);
```

Comment: Try $cookieStore, it is super easy to use.

Comment: I don't think $cookieStore is available in the config block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wanted to set specific http headers on every http request, so this is my solution:

I'm using the run function because in config I couldn't access cookies, see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

```
app.run(function run( $http, $cookies ){
  $http.defaults.headers.common["X-AUTH-TOKEN"] = $cookies['AUTH-TOKEN'];
});
```

If you don't want to use the run function for that configuration (because it's hard to unit-test), you can write an interceptor for the $httpProvider, similar to this: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/76df8d1f037db87f4a0b

Comment: `Run blocks typically contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.` -> From AngularJS docs, just an additional info...

Comment: @JuanHBiscaia you are right, the right way would be to write an interceptor like here: https://gist.github.com/lpsBetty/76df8d1f037db87f4a0b  I will update my answer

Answer (score 30):

You can inject `$cookies` manually:

```
myApp.config(function() {
  var $cookies;
  angular.injector(['ngCookies']).invoke(['$cookies', function(_$cookies_) {
    $cookies = _$cookies_;
  }]);

  // here you can use $cookies as usual
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can write something like this:

```
$cookiesProvider.$get()["XSRF-TOKEN"]
```

Comment: This causes `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module x due to:
TypeError: $cookiesProvider.$get is not a function`, although console logs that $cookiesProvider has $get at that moment